# angular-devkit/build-angular version 0.13.4 - configuration.output has an unknown property 'futureEmitAssets'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just upgraded a project from angular-devkit/build-angular v0.11.4 to v0.13.4. I now receive the following error:

````
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output has an unknown property 'futureEmitAssets'. 
These properties are valid:
   object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkCallbackName?, chunkFilename?, chunkLoadTimeout?, crossOriginLoading?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolNamespace?, filename?, globalObject?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, jsonpScriptType?, library?, libraryExport?, libraryTarget?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine?, webassemblyModuleFilename? }
   -> Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output has an unknown property 'futureEmitAssets'. These properties are valid:
   object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkCallbackName?, chunkFilename?, chunkLoadTimeout?, crossOriginLoading?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolNamespace?, filename?, globalObject?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, jsonpScriptType?, library?, libraryExport?, libraryTarget?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine?, webassemblyModuleFilename? }
   -> Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.```
````

My `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ui": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/css/simple-sidebar.css",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/css/simple-sidebar.css",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ui-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ui:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ui"
}
```

My startup command is `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.js`

I cannot find any instance of `futureEmitAssets` in my code. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: post your `angular.json` here

Comment: Added angular.json

Comment: What angular command are you using example `ng build -c .......`

Comment: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.js`

Comment: removing package-lock.json and reinstalling npm modules worked for me

Answer (score 6):

You need webpack@4.29 or above to fix that.

Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8883